# Cursor doesn't jump down in cell below in excel

Tags: excel, vba, cursor, tracking

I'm really new in coding and now i have a little problem. 
I have made a code, which can track changes in my Excel Sheets. The code is working just fine, but when i have written in a cell and then press enter, the cursor jump back in the same cell. I can't find a answer anywere and i have tried advanced options in Excel.

```
    'Tracker
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
 If ActiveSheet.Name = "Changes" Then Exit Sub
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
 NewVal = Target.Value
 Application.Undo
 oldVal = Target.Value
 lr = Sheets("Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Sheets("Changes").Range("A" & lr) = Now
 Sheets("Changes").Range("B" & lr) = ActiveSheet.Name
 Sheets("Changes").Range("C" & lr) = Target.Address
 Sheets("Changes").Range("D" & lr) = oldVal
 Sheets("Changes").Range("E" & lr) = NewVal
 Sheets("Changes").Range("F" & lr) = UserName
 Target = NewVal
 Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to grad the user's selection before running undo, then re-select it later.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sel As Range, UserName, NewVal, oldVal, lr As Long

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Changes" Then Exit Sub

    'check there's a range to remember
    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then Set sel = Selection

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    UserName = Environ("USERNAME")
    NewVal = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    oldVal = Target.Value

    With Sheets("Changes")
        lr = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & lr) = Now
        .Range("B" & lr) = ActiveSheet.Name
        .Range("C" & lr) = Target.Address
        .Range("D" & lr) = oldVal
        .Range("E" & lr) = NewVal
        .Range("F" & lr) = UserName
    End With
    Target = NewVal

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    're-select any previous selection
    If Not sel Is Nothing Then sel.Select

 End Sub
```

Note: `Target` can be >1 cell, or a whole column/row.  Your code will crash in those cases, because `.Value` in those cases is an array, not a single value. Handling this so your code is robust is a bit more complex.